# Sharing a variable between a class and its member

Tags: c#, oop, class-design

If you have a class that contains a state variable and two member classes that need access to it and operate asynchronously. What is the best way to implement this?

An example

```
 public enum RestaurantState
 {
     BREAKFAST,
     LUNCH,
     DINNER
 }

 public class Restaurant
 {
     //Below need access to state
     private DeliveryMan pizzaDriver ;
     private Supplier butcherShop ;

     internal RestaurantState state ; 
 }

public DeliveryMan
{
     //Uses a System.Timers.Timer
     //Wakes up and does work every a minute
     //Needs to inform state of restaurant
}

public Supplier
{
     //Waits and listens for requests to accept deliveries
     //If suppliers run out we need to change the restaurant state based on our own  current state
}
```

These classes operate asynchronously. Both DeliveryMan and Supplier classes need to be able to read/write the state. DeliveryMan pushes out the state of the restaurant and the Supplier listens for its supplier's status.

Is there a better way to design this or a way to implement it with minimal coupling without giving DeliveryMan or Supplier a reference to its owner Restaurant.

Comment: since ResturantState is declared as private how to you expect other classes to updated it ?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the access modifier to internal

Comment: If those are your actual states, I'd recommend making it a class with 2 bools like in my (edited) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well i would pass the state as constructor parameter to your two inner classes and considering that it is a reference type it can be modified as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Say the state continually changes and deliveryMan needs to always give the current state

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create events on the `DeliveryMan` and `Supplier` classes that are fired when the state needs to be updated.  The Restaurant can subscribe to these events and update its own state accordingly when the event handler(s) are invoked.

Comment: I thought of giving the member classes a delegate to get/set the state. I appreciate your answer and thinking on it.

Answer (score 1):

If `RestaurantState` is or can be made into an object that holds the state rather than the state itself, then you can do as @Davide's answer and pass it in to the constructor.

However if it's a value type like an `enum` then I think `event`s are the way to go.

`DeliveryMan` raises an event with the new state, that `Restaurant` listens to and updates it's internal state.

`Restaurant` can then call a `StateChanged` method or something similar on `Supplier` when the state changes.  Or `Supplier` can raise an `event` with a special `RestaurantStateEventArgs` or something that the `Restaurant` can listen to and populate the event args with the state.

Depending on the use-case though, it may not be terrible to just have a reference to `Restaurant` even though it does become tightly coupled.

**Edit**: Actually if `DeliveryMan` and `Supplier` need access to `RestaurantState` then they are already somewhat tied to Restaurants, so unless you have a more generic type of "state" than `RestaurantState` they are already coupled.

Sometimes it's good to take a step back and see if

a) decoupling is actually helpful in a particular scenario and
   b) whether what you're doing is actually decoupled enough to be useful.

In this scenario, you still couldn't reuse `DeliveryMan` and `Supplier` for say a furniture store.

As a sidenote:

```
OPEN,
CLOSED,
LOW_ON_SUPPLIES
```

These aren't really the best choices for an enum, since they're not all mutually exclusive.  it may be better if it were a class so:

```
public class RestaurantState
{
  public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
  public bool IsLowOnSupplies { get; set; }
}
```

In that case, @Davide's answer for passing RestaurantState into the constructor of `DeliveryMan` and `Supplier` works well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and improve the example. If I make Restaurant State a class and I pass it through the constructor, will reading butcherShop.parentState reflect any and all changes in restaurant.state?

Comment: @eddiehobbes if you make RestaurantState a class that holds the real state info, then you can, but you will have to do something like `butcherShop.RestaurantState.RealState`.  It's a little clunky if there's one one property, but it does work nicely if you have multiple types of state, like `IsOpen` `CurrentlyServing` (e.g. Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner), etc.

Comment: @eddiehobbes I'd still consider whether decoupling in this particular scenario actually gives you any benefits.  If you can't use the classes with anything other than `Restaurant`, then they're already implicitly coupled, not through code, but just by design, e.g. RestaurantState doesn't make sense for anything other than Restaurants.

Comment: So would giving each a reference to its parent make sense in this case? Or the alternative or making events/delegates to gain access

Comment: @eddiehobbes I'd just give a reference to the parent, unless there's a compelling reason not to.  The main benefit you get from decoupling is that you can reuse the classes in other scenarios, however since they need to know restaurant states, you wouldn't get that benefit.  So unless there's another benefit to not have a reference to the parent, or if passing a reference to the parent becomes a hassle (say when updating the reference), I'd just do with the simplest solution, having a reference to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the state out of the restaurant class and make a `StateManager` class that was a singleton or a factory for the rest of the other classes. Its hard to give a more complete answer since your OO design doesnt give much to go on.

```
var restaurant = new Restaurant();
var supplier = new Supplier();
StateManager.GetState(restaurant);
StateManager.GetState(supplier);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `Order` class that contains the information you need in another class. Also use a Queue which you check on a Timer event. When you dequeue an Order, look at Order.State (for instance). Put the Queue in a public static class with Enqueue and Dequeue methods.

When the DeliveryMan timer event fires, dequeue the Order.

You mention that everything is async, so you might check out ConcurrentQueue. Since Supplier waits for notification, you can use IObserver/IObservable to send a stream message to Supplier with a serialized Order object ...

Just some thoughts that might help out.